# How to get the properties of the functor $F$?

Tags: homological-algebra, modules

Let $\Gamma$ be an artin algebra. We denote by $mod \Gamma$ the category of finitely generated left $\Gamma$-modules. $D: mod \Gamma \rightarrow mod \Gamma$ is the standard duality. $I_0(\Gamma)$ is the injective envelope of $\Gamma$. Set $S= \{ X \in mod \Gamma | $ there is an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow I_0 \rightarrow I_1$ with $I_0,I_1 \in add I_0(\Gamma) \}$.

1. How to show the functor $F=D Hom(-, I_0(\Gamma)): S \rightarrow  mod End_{\Gamma}(I_0(\Gamma))$ is an equivalence?
2. If the dominant dimension of $\Gamma \geq 2$, then $\Gamma \in S$. Then how to get that $F(\Gamma)$ is a generator and cognerator of $mod End_{\Gamma}(I_0(\Gamma))$? (A module is called a generator and cogenerator if it contains all idecomposable projecitve and injecitve modules as direct summands)